# Problem with Sticky Header, content below it not showing ( React, Ant Design )

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

Header Component

```
       <Header
          className="site-layout-header"
          style={{
            position: "sticky",
            top: 0,
            zIndex: 999,
            width: "100%",
            padding: 30,
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            ...style,
          }}
        >
        {children}
       </Header>
```

Below this I am using header component like this

```
const IncidentProfile = (props: any) => {
  const { record } = props.location?.state || {};
  return (
    <>
      <Header record={record} />
      <Content
        className="site-layout-background"
        style={{
          padding: 24,
        }}
      >
        <h1>Incident Profile Page {record?.name}</h1>
      </Content>
    </>
  );
};
```

When the Header component height increases dynamically, it scrolls and stay sticky but the content below it is not showing.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you clearify what "is not showing" means? Is it behind the header or is it not rendering?

Comment: It is not rendering below the header